# Is it possible to push an environment variable on my machine to GitHub?

Tags: python, macos, authentication, github, environment-variables

## Summary

I work with several python scripts that use a proprietary application. This application requires authentication to use its API. I want to push the system in its entirety to Github to keep it working the same.

---

Authentication happens one of two ways.

## *Quick but less secure authentication*

Create a constructor for the application within the python script
(name of actual application left out)

```
    from pyapplication import Application 
    application = Application(username='something' password='123456')
```

## *Involved but more secure authentication*

1. Create a separate .applicationrc file in the same directory as the script. This file will store the credentials.
2. Create an environment variable to refer to this .applicationrc file.
3. Run `chmod 600` on the file to prevent global readability.

The application only recognizes PYAPPLICATIONRC. as a valid environment variable

---

## File Structure

Below is the relevant code and the files where the code is located:

**The .applicationrc file:**

> [auth]
>
> username=something
>
> password=123456

**The Python script:**

> from pyapplication import Application
>
> application = Application()

**The environment variable:**

> PYAPPLICATIONRC = /path/to/.applicationrc

---

## Question

The system works on my local machine (a macOS High Sierra 10.13.1).  I would like to push this environment variable to GitHub to keep the system intact on the group repository.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project I'm working on, my lead copies his `.env` file to a file called `sample.env` and pushes it with the code. Then we can ust run `cp sample.env .env` That will be different depending on your OS of course. I would include those instructions in your `README.md` for clarity. We use Bitbucket instead of Github but I doubt there will  be any difference there.

Alternatively you could include some code like `os.environ["PYAPPLICATIONRC"] = "/path/to/.applicationrc"`

Comment: The ".env" file you refer to is the one native to machine correct (i.e., the one returned by printenv)?

Comment: nope, it's a local `.env` file in the root of the project folder that our express server references. If you need to alter the global .env use `os.environ["EV"]`